# Caldroid disable specific dates

Tags: android, calendar

I searched a lot of datepicker and calendarview libraries to disable specific dates. Caldroid seems to have option to disable dates but it can only disable dates corresponding to current date. But I want to disable particular dates like 10, 18, 21, etc. there is no option for that. So it would be a great help if anyone can mention how to do it in caldroid or in any other library. What I did:

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void change(View v){

        CaldroidFragment mCaldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt( CaldroidFragment.START_DAY_OF_WEEK, CaldroidFragment.MONDAY );
        mCaldroidFragment.setArguments( args );

        ArrayList<String> disabledDates = new ArrayList<String>();
        disabledDates.add("10");
        disabledDates.add("20");
        disabledDates.add("30");
        ArrayList<Date> dd = new ArrayList<Date>();

        for(int i=0; i<disabledDates.size(); i++){
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
            dd.add(cal.getTime());
        }


        mCaldroidFragment.setDisableDates(dd);
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.frame , mCaldroidFragment ).commit();



    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of  `dd` ?

Comment: dd is just the ArrayList<Date> which is used in Caldroid's sample code for inserting dates. I tried to insert my ArrayList `disabledDates` into `dd` but it only disabled 9,10,11 dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example works for me.

Add the following UI elements to your `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/customize_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="customize"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapt your `MainActivity` as follows:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    args.putInt( CaldroidFragment.START_DAY_OF_WEEK, CaldroidFragment.MONDAY    );
    caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);

    // Attach to the activity
    FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.calendar1, caldroidFragment);
    t.commit();

    final Button customizeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.customize_button);
    // Customize the calendar
    customizeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Set disabled dates
            try {
                ArrayList<Date> disabledDates = new ArrayList<Date>();

                disabledDates.add(getDate("2016-06-16"));
                disabledDates.add(getDate("2016-06-20"));
                disabledDates.add(getDate("2016-06-30"));

                // Customize
                caldroidFragment.setDisableDates(disabledDates);
                // Refresh
                caldroidFragment.refreshView();

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }

  private Date getDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();

    // month start at 1. Need to minus 1 to get javaMonth
    calendar.set(year, month - 1, day);

    return calendar.getTime();
  }

  private Date getDate(String strDate) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = format.parse(strDate);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();

    calendar.setTime(date);

    return calendar.getTime();
  }
}
```

When you click on the CUSTOMIZE button it will disable the following dates:

1. 16 June 2016
2. 20 June 2016
3. 30 June 2016

Comment: Nothing happened. Also how to add dates dynamically as my dates will be coming frm web service?

Comment: Just wanted to ensure your dates are correct which is why I populated the ArrayList manually. If you ask Caldroid to refresh after you call `setDisableDates` i.e. `mCaldroidFragment.refreshView();`

Comment: Yes, I called refreshView() after `mCaldroidFragment.setDisableDates(dd);`, but nothing changed.

Comment: Its the sample code from Caldroid. Of course it will work. But as I said in the starting, this code depends on the current date. And then disables dates +days or -days as per current date. No use when you want to disable random dates.

Comment: Cool, but your sample code doesn't include `refreshView` so I added an example which is more complete. Will see if I can modify to disable random dates for you

Comment: I have added a `getDate` method which you can use to populate your `ArrayList` of dates you would like disabled from your webservice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114231/discussion-between-somnath-pal-and-clive-seebregts).